# I download the laravel website file from cpanel and try to run in xampp but it could not run and throw an error?

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

[image]

The error it gives is

> Warning: require_once(header.php): Failed to open stream: No such file
> or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test4\public\index.php on line 1
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'header.php'
> (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\test4\public\index.php:1 Stack trace: 
> #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\test4\server.php(21): require_once() 
> #1 {main} thrown
> in C:\xampp\htdocs\test4\public\index.php on line 1

note there is no index.php file in cPanel but its run but its not run on xampp localhost and throw error

Answer (score 0):

In order to run the laravel files you have to follow a few steps:

1. Delete the `vendor` folder which contains the dependencies
2. Open up a command prompt in the same folder and run `composer install` to re-install the dependencies
3. Then open the `.env` file and update the database credentials
4. Type this command : `php artisan migrate` to migrate your database
5. Finally run `php artisan serve` to serve the laravel application.